# I want to compare two datasets to determine which variables they share

Tags: data-processing, large-data

I have two RNAseq read-outs for two groups and would like to compare them. These data appear as a gene and a value. I would like to determine which genes are shared between the two datasets but they are very large and doing this manually will take a long time.
Thanks!

Comment: If I understand, you have two tables each having 2 columns, `gene`, which is a string, and `value`, which is a number. I think this is more of a programming question than a statistics question.

Comment: This is a programming question. It shouldn't be migrated, though, since answers will heavily depend on your environment/language. Consider adding this information and requesting migration to SO.

Comment: I agree, this is a programming question. Please move it to StackOverflow, so that if we are competent in your programming language of choice, we can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've moved over to StackOverflow

Comment: May be we will need more information about the technology being used to get the datasets, the language that is used, so as to get a good answer.